# How to upgrade to a new installed gitlab runner version?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I try to update my single gitlab runner from 11.0 to 11.3.1
and followed the instruction on the gitlab [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html).

*sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner* will confirm that I have the new version installed:

> gitlab-runner is already the newest version (11.3.1).

The last updates like 10.* to 11.0 worked absolutely fine but this time
the runner still stays on 11.0 (in -help and gitlab-ci web ui).

A restart of the runner don't change anything so it looks like I miss a major step for the update some how.

It would be great to find out what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance. :-)

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1

*(I'm relatively new in the linux and gitlab world so it could be something obvious)*

Used update command:

```
# For Debian/Ubuntu/Mint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner
```

Comment: Out of curioisity, does sudo /usr/share/gitlab-runner/post-install actually do something in your case?

Comment: No this just don't do anything in my case, but after this I have found the answer to the problem after spending more time to investigate. (already posted here) Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok the problem was solved by using the manual update described at:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html

> Stop the service (you need elevated command prompt as before):
>
> `sudo gitlab-runner stop`
>
> Download the binary to replace Runner's executable:
>
> ```
> sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-386
> sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64
> ```
>
> You can download a binary for every available version as described in
>   Bleeding Edge - download any other tagged release.
>
> Give it permissions to execute:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner
> ```
>
> Start the service:
>
> ```
> sudo gitlab-runner start
> ```

**"latest"** - may install a beta so it is important to select the right tag (also described in the link)